# Nginx proxy_next_upstream with different URI modification

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

We have a need to set up multiple up-stream server, and use proxy_next_upstream to a backup, if the main server returns 404. However, the URI for up-stream backup server is different than the one towards main server, so I don't know whether this can be possible.

In detail, below config snippet works fine (if URIs are the same to all up-stream servers):

> ```
> upstream upstream-proj-a {
>    server server1.test.com;
>    server server2.test.com backup;
> }
>
> server {
>     listen 80;
>     listen [::]:80;
>
>     server_name www.test.com;
>     location /proj/proj-a {
>
>         proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_404;
>
>         proxy_pass http://upstream-proj-a/lib/proj/proj-a;
> }
> ```

For a request of http://test.com/proj/proj-a/file, it will first try to request http://server1.test.com/lib/proj/proj-a/file, if return 404 or timeout, then try http://server2.test.com/lib/proj/proj-a/file. This is good.

However, now for server2, it can only accept URL like http://server2.test.com/lib/proj/proj-a-internal/file, which is different than the URI towards the main server. If only considering the backup server, I can write like below:

> ```
> proxy_pass http://server2.test.com/lib/proj/proj-a-internal
> ```

However looks like I can not have different proxy_pass for different upstream server combining proxy_next_upstream.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It looks like it can achieve the goal using Lua scripting. May update with an answer myself since no any answers...

Answer (score 1):

I found a work-around using simple proxy_pass, and set local host as the backup upstream server, then do rewrite on behalf of the real backup upstream server.

The config is like below:

```
upstream upstream-proj-a {

   server server1.test.com:9991;
   # Use localhost as backup
   server localhost backup;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    resolver 127.0.1.1;

    server_name www.test.com;

    location /lib/proj/proj-a {
        # Do rewrite then proxy_pass to real upstream server
        rewrite /lib/proj/proj-a/(.*) /lib/proj/proj-a-internal/$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://server2.test.com:9992;
    }

    location /proj/proj-a {
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_404;
        proxy_pass http://upstream-proj-a/lib/proj/proj-a;
    }
}
```

It works fine, but the only side-effect is that, when a request needs to go to the backup server, it creates another new HTTP request from localhost to localhost which seems to double the load to nginx. The goal is to transfer quite big files, and I am not sure if this impacts performance or not, especially if all the protocols are https instead of http.

Comment: You can use `proxy_pass http://server2.test.com:9992/lib/proj/proj-a-internal;` at your first block and skip that rewrite rule. I needed the same and finished up using a similar config, however I'm using localhost with different port as a backup server to transform request URI. I'm also using HTTPS only for backup upstream, so I'm proxying requests to upstream server group via plain HTTP for the performance considerations, and use HTTPS only in the backup server block listening on different port `proxy_pass` directive.

Comment: Yes this makes sense. I used to have a Lua solution, too, fyi. @IvanShatsky

Comment: I'm using OpenResty so it will be interesting to see the Lua solution too. Right now I'm thinking about backup server listening on unix socket rather than TCP port, for the performance considerations (didn't try it yet).